# Is there a simple way to prevent a WPF RichTextBox from autogrowing?

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox

Is there a simple way to prevent a RichTextBox from increasing its height when you add more lines to it?

What I have tested so far:

- Set VerticalScrollBars="Auto"
- Set VerticalScrollBars="Visible"
- Set AcceptReturns="False"
- Set AcceptReturns="True" :-)

None of the above helps however. The RTB is inside a Grid row that is autosizing and the user can control the row height with a GridSplitter. I want the RTB to honor the splitter and not auto-resize as more text gets submitted.

### Edit

Worth noting, incidentally, is that once I resize the Grid.Row (with the GridSplitter) the RTB is restrained and can no longer autogrow. I guess that if I could just, somehow, emulate resizing , just a pixel, when the form loads it would "solve" the issue. A bit hackish of course ...

### Edit

(Relevant XAML example)

```
<Window
x:Class="Test.Window"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="TEST" 
Height="609.8" Width="848"
Background="#000000"
FontFamily="Segoe UI"
>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel 
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Background="#333333"
            >
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid 
            Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1"
            Width="Auto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="#222222"
        />
    <GridSplitter 
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" Background="#222222" 
            />
    <Grid
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
            MinWidth="100"
            />
    <GridSplitter
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="3" Background="#222222" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Grid>
            <RichTextBox MinHeight="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <RichTextBox.Document>
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit tempor, class a cum odio diam nec ullamcorper eget, duis curae dictum rutrum cursus tristique rhoncus. Curabitur montes erat sociis feugiat dictumst eu faucibus, dapibus habitasse platea parturient dignissim fringilla tortor, et ridiculus vehicula ac vel sem."></Run>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox.Document>
            </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How do you add more lines if you set the AcceptReturns property to false? Are you doing it programmatically? Then include your repo code please.

Comment: Yes, what I have is actually a custom control that emulates a console window, to be embedded into my app. I based it on RTB and intercepts all keystrokes (to prevent moving the cursor into the prompt etc.), including ENTER to kick off a "command entered" event and produce another prompt afterwards. So "linefeeds" works even with AcceptReturns=false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way, set a height to the RTB (or to the Grid Row in which the RTB is placed).

It keeps growing since there is no set boundary. Its parent, the Grid, is autosized with its children, so the children are spoiled.

Comment: It's ok for the RTB to grow but only when the user drags the horizontal splitter controlling the height of its Grid.Row. Is there no way to accomplish that?

Comment: @JonasRembratt Try to add the rtb to a scrollviewer, and add the scrollviewer into the row, set the scrollviewer's height as stretch. I do not got a device to try it out yet.

Comment: Hm. Good idea but it didn't help; I get the exact same behavior. Maybe I need to combine a ScrollView with some settings?

Comment: Had better post the relevant xaml code to c what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for not doing that immediately. I added an exampl to the OP.

Comment: Ok, I feel like an ass. Just setting a Height (not MaxHeight) to the RTB's Grid.Row did the trick. Somehow I just assumed the splitter would require the row height to be set to "Auto" to work. Sometimes the brain works in mysterious ways. 

If you would be so kind as to modify your reply to suggest "Height" instead of "MaxHeight" I will go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonasRembratt hi my answer has been edited;) Sorry for not quite responsive (on vacation)